# What is the purpose of minimum points required for initial meld?

Tags: game-design, canasta, mechanics, rummy

In Canasta and several variants of Contract-Rummy, like [Rummikub](https://rummikub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2600-English-1.pdf) and [Kaluki](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/kaluki1.html), there is an "**initial meld**" rule: The first melds put down by a player must consist of cards to a total value of at least X points.

From a game design perspective, what does this accomplish? What is the purpose? What problem is being solved here? Is it so that new players entering the board are contributing a large number of pieces on their first turn? If so, why would that necessarily be a good thing?

Comment: I’m only familiar with Rummikub, and this is purely speculation; without the initial meld requirement, maybe players were hoarding tiles until they can put them all out in one go, and the rule was put in to prevent that?

Comment: The Rummikub rule does not prevent a player from hording tiles - a limit to the maximum initial meld would do that, but a minimum inital meld does not.

Comment: I would guess it is to make the game more challenging as you get closer to winning but I can't say for sure.

Comment: My wild guess would be that not having that rule leads to degenerate games in some way - not enough open values, like you suggest, or maybe it results in a dominant strategy of rushing lots of small melds.

Comment: With or without a maximum initial meld rule, players are still forced to play tiles for two turns. At least in my version, you can't play anything other than the initial meld on the turn you play it.

Answer (score 2):

In the version of Canasta I played long ago - the higher your sum of total points from the previous rounds are - the more points you need in your initial mold.

- This gives the players that are behind an advantage, they can play a faster game since it is easier to open
- In the earlier stages of the game it makes it harder to take the stack which might influence what kind of cards you throw away.

This means, there is a different dynamic between the start and end of each round. The first few rounds are kind of save (and there is nothing to pick up), you try to figure out what your partner has or not has (and your opponent) by what they trash.

The later stages are more about bluffing or trying to grab a big stack - each card you throw away has to given much more thought to not give the opponent an opportunity.

Comment: I want to say, that I think that this is a compelling answer, however this mechanic that you describe does not apply to RummiKub, or at-least the versions that I play, which always puts the limit at 30 points.   So this cannot be the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many old games (including card games) were [designed for gambling](https://www.britannica.com/topic/playing-card#:%7E:text=still%20played%20for%20money%3B%20the%20practice%20of%20playing%20games%20of%20skill%20strictly%20for%20fun%20is%20historically%20recent.). This often explains many unintuitive rules, especially scoring rules and bonuses.

So one answer to "What is the purpose [of an initial meld requirement]?" is simply, to "unbalance" the game and increase potential winnings. Initial meld requirements allow a player/team to establish early melds over the other team, which makes scoring points in the hand easier. Without the initial meld requirement, the other team could claim other melding territory more easily, which lets them fight back quicker.

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit by describing _how_ the meld requirement actually accomplishes that. Otherwise, it just sounds like a guess.